# How to implement the map with Xamarin forms android for free?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to  implement the
map with Xamarin forms android. Rather than google, I need an alternate which should be free.  Any possibility  of resource which fulfill my needs.

Comment: what features do you need that are not available using the free Android Google map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the community. You can refer to the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/map) the Microsoft provided. These articles can teach you how to use the map on Xamarin.Forms. In addition, the google map is free for you and you can use the google map as your choice.

If you have any other questions, please feel free to comment.

Comment: on billing option , they instructed to set billing account before free trial ends.
After free trial, is we need to pay?  If so, if I failed to pay, is  the API can continue working in my app.

Comment: Which api you need to use? Most of google map API is free for people to use. If you want to use the billing products, you need to pay for it.

Comment: Yeah, I  have to use map API.  I thought that, that need to pay. Thank you for your kind replay.

Comment: Are they really free: https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/ ?